# How to add visual effects to mouse clicks or system events

Tags: .net, windows, customization

How do I programmatically interact with the mouse and mouse pointer, system-wide?

I would like to achieve the following:

1. The mouse pointer sparkles (or changes color, or shape) when the user clicks a mouse button;
2. When an event occurs (for example, an email arrives/notification is triggered, or a set time is passed), the mouse pointer emits sparks or changes colour.

I don't want to use (auto)hotkeys or any existing application to achieve the outcomes, it must all be via coding; ideally C# or VB.Net, or C++ as a last resort.

I have looked online but only found similar articles explaining how to customise the pointer image.

Environment is any Windows system from 7 onwards.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

This is a coding exercise; I've looked for solutions but I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for specifically.